# Possible to use CSS transitions with textarea rows value?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition

In all the years I've been developing websites this situation has never cropped up before and I'm not sure that what I'm attempting to do is even possible.

I have a `React` component with a `textarea`. It's initial state is rendered with a height of 1 row like this :

```
state = {
  rows: 1
}

...

<textarea 
   ...
   rows={this.state.rows ? this.state.rows : 1}
   onFocus={this.onFocus}
   ...
/>
```

The `onFocus` function changes the rows state to 5, thereby expanding the `textarea`.

This works perfectly, but I'm now trying to add CSS transitions to the `textarea` so it expands nicely instead of just instantly expanding.

Everything I've tried doesn't work, for example :

```
textarea#content {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

...so my question is - is it not possible to use CSS transitions in this way? I did some googling and couldn't find any answers which leads me to believe that it isn't, but I just want to make sure before I set about achieving this another way.

Comment: *Everything I've tried doesn't work* What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of trying to do some kind of transition on the rows, why not work with the height?

Comment: @ScottMarcus `transition: all 2s ease-in-out;` - doesn't work for one. @mwarren that will be my next move if I can't do it this way. But I'm curious now as to whether it can actually be done this way as I've never run up against this before.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say how React might be involved here, but for a `transition` to work, the CSS property being transitioned must have a default value set for it. You are **indirectly** affecting the `height` property by changing the `rows`, but you are not actually specifying that you want the `height` to change, so you can't transition the `height` if you are only indirectly changing it. Also, there is no CSS `rows` property, so no luck on transitioning that either.

The solution is to not set the `height` indirectly with `rows` in the first place. Set the `height` directly and set a default value for `height` in the CSS.

And, you really don't even need JavaScript to do this:

```css
textarea {
 height:1em; /* Initial value required for transitions to work */
 transition:height 1s ease-in-out; /* configure the transition*/
}

/* Style to be applied automatically when the textarea recievs the focus */
textarea:focus {
  height:5em; /* A change in this property will trigger the transition */
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I guessed. It's a shame it can't be used like this though as that would have been really nice! Thanks for the feedback Scott.

Comment: @spice You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer. Good luck.

Comment: Would this even work on something like rows? I thought transitions didn't work on properties that were integer based.

Comment: @JudeDesir As I stated, it won't work on `rows` because `rows` isnt' a CSS property. But, transitions will work on ***any*** CSS property value that can be computed to have a starting and ending value - whole or fraction values are both just fine.